# PCF8575c changes address in I2C Scanner

Tags: led, esp32

I want to connect a PCF8575c pin extender to an ESP32, so that I can light 12 LEDs. The problem is that after the connection, when I try to use an I2C Scanner, it shows me a lot of different addresses, not a constant one. Could this happen from a pin fault? I am using this library:
https://github.com/xreef/PCF8575_library

Also, the I2C scanner can be found here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/

And the pins that I use for the LEDs are defined this way:

```
  pcf8575.pinMode(P0, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P1, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P2, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P3, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P5, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P6, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P11, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P12, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P14, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P15, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P16, OUTPUT);
  pcf8575.pinMode(P17, OUTPUT);
```

The link to the exact PCF8575c:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2038559527.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.3f8331ebu0zuwr&algo_pvid=5e9fc157-a422-4847-acf4-8618a2d365ea&algo_expid=5e9fc157-a422-4847-acf4-8618a2d365ea-2&btsid=0ab6f82415840969999872503e3228&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: What are the addresses it gives you?

Comment: Have you configured the A0/A1/A2 jumpers on the board?

Comment: I agree with Majenko. That really sounds like unconnected and thus floating address pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the back of the module. There are 3 groups of 3 solder pads each, marked with A0, A1 and A2. With these pads you can set the 3 least significant bits of the address.

On the images in your product link these pads are unconnected. The middle pin is the address pin. The left pad (which is connected to a trace) is Vcc, the right pad (which is connected to the big trace area) is ground. By connecting the middle pad with ground, you set the address bit to zero. By connecting it to Vcc, you set it to 1.

As the pads are unconnected, the address pins are floating. In that state, the pin is reacting to random electrical noise, thus changing state randomly. So also the address changes randomly.

You need to connect every address pin to either ground or Vcc by adding a solder bridge to the pads.